# windowControllerDidLoadNib never called in Document Based application

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument

I have a swift document based cocoa application that uses storyboard. In my application, the method

```
windowControllerDidLoadNib()
```

defined in my document file (that of course extends NSDocument) is never called, even when opening new documents from **file->Open**.

Why is this happening? If it will never be called, how am I supposed to put the document content in a view contained in the window?

Of course `windowNibName()` is overriden, so the file containing the document class is the owner for the window, according to Apple's documentation.

Update: when the new window should be create, I can see the folloowing error message in the console:
BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MEMORYSTATUS] add: "Operation not supported" - 0x2d

Comment: - (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)windowController; this is the correct signature in objc (derive swift one); I think you have wrong method and missing keyword override

Comment: I recommend that you don't mingle windowcontroller and document together. Inspire yourself with sample code called Lister It's Obj-C but gives you idea how to correctly work with framework; not against it. I mean which methods to work with

Comment: @Marek H: where can I find that sample?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html